# What are the positive integral solution sets of $a^2+ab+b^2=343k$?

Tags: number-theory

I had encountered a problem in which we had to find all positive integers $(a,b,k)$ such that $a^2+ab+b^2=343k$. I  had never had a general approach to solve such an equation having three variables. Would someone please help me to solve this equation?

Comment: Hint: Write this as $a^3 \equiv b^3$ mod 343 and $a \neq b$ mod 343. Also $343=7^3.$